# Cannot resolve the symbol HttpPost, DefaultHttpClient, ClientProtocolException

Tags: android, http

I've gone through similar questions on stackoverflow & even googled my problems but haven't found a solution, so finally posting here.
I'm new to this topic hence, please forgive any silly mistakes.

Below is my module level gradle:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.aishwaryat.httpcommunication"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.5'
}
```

Comment: The build they are using for this legacy package is lil bit different, so there are some different names for the same classes. But it is better for you to migrate to new HTTP Client, like OkHTTP

Comment: Alright! I'll go through it now! Thank You!

Comment: I have read somewhere in SO that someone has faced the same problem though mentioning the `useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'` in the build.gradle, but the app compiles, builds, and runs fine. Just an advice, why don't you look into the Google Volley library (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/), this is not a solution to your problem, but a better approach, IMO.

Comment: Yes, I did read volley & prepared a small demo as well. It is a better approach. But I want a solution to this, since it is working on my trainer's PC it should work on mine as well. I've forwarded my error to my trainer as well. I'm a fresher, been 7days only. :)

Comment: It wll be a best approach if you will use `Volley` or `Retrofit`  with `OkHttp`

Comment: Alright! Thank You all! :)

Comment: Does your trainer's PC use `targerSdkVersion 23`? Also, did you try `cleaning` and `rebuilding` your project?

Comment: Yes, it uses 23. I just cleaned & rebuilt my project. No effect.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari, is the rebuild successful? Or did gradle throw any errors? If  the build was successful, that means your app would work, just like I said previously that some people faced the problem that though the app ran fine, it was filled with error marks. Maybe that is a problem with Android Studio.

Comment: and please respond with @SajibAcharya, otherwise, I wouldn't get notifications from you.

Comment: @SajibAcharya, no errors after rebuild.

Comment: @AishwaryaTiwari, great, that means your app will work just fine. Though you will not be explicitly able to review any errors and that is a real bad user experience. There is really not much you could do, so `volley` is your option here. This is what google actually wants, I guess, forcing its users to use its technologies.

Comment: @SajibAcharya, Haha! Yeah maybe!
Btw, I used volley & I'm done with the assigned task. :)